# Building the Qt QIBASE driver on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, firebird, qmake

I'm having trouble building the QIBASE SQL driver for Qt to be able to use Firebird with Qt on OS X.

I found this quick guide: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qibase but it doesn't seem to be correct.

Firebird is installed and it's header files are:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Headers/
```

and the dylib files are:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Libraries/
```

I have downloaded the Qt 4.8.4 source from: http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-lib and extracted it to:

```
~/devel/qt
```

So I changed the code on the first link from this:

```
cd $QTDIR/src/plugins/sqldrivers/ibase
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/opt/interbase/include" "LIBS+=-L/opt/interbase/lib -lfbclient" ibase.pro
make
```

To:

```
cd ~/devel/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/ibase
qmake -spec macx-g++ "INCLUDEPATH+=/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Headers" "LIBS+=-L/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Libraries -lfbclient" ibase.pro
make
```

And I get the following errors from the make:

```
In file included from main.cpp:44:
../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:47:46: error: QtSql/private/qsqlcachedresult_p.h: No such file or directory
In file included from main.cpp:44:
../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:58: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:70: error: ‘QSqlCachedResult’ has not been declared
../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:70: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
make[1]: *** [debug/main.o] Error 1
make: *** [debug] Error 2
```

So I run `mdfind qsqlcachedresult_p.h | grep qsqlcachedresult_p.h` and the only results I get are:

```
~/devel/qt/src/sql/kernel/qsqlcachedresult_p.h
~/devel/qt/include/QtSql/private/qsqlcachedresult_p.h
```

Bare in mind it doesn't seem to exist as a part of the Qt SDK which I have installed and is located in the default place of `/Library/Frameworks/Qt*.framework`.

So I try to add the devel qt src files to the INCLUDEPATH and try running qmake again:

```
cd ~/devel/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/ibase
qmake -spec macx-g++ "INCLUDEPATH+=~/devel/qt/include" "INCLUDEPATH+=/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Headers" "LIBS+=-L/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Libraries -lfbclient" ibase.pro
make
```

But now I get a whole bunch of "does not name a type" erros along with `error: #error "Qt has not been ported to this architecture"` and `error: #error "Qt not configured correctly, please run configure"` and `error: ../../src/corelib/global/qconfig.h: No such file or directory`. The whole lot as returned by make is here:

```
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:62,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qnamespace.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:47,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/qconfig.h:1:46: error: ../../src/corelib/global/qconfig.h: No such file or directory
make -f Makefile.Debug
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.8/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtSql -I/usr/include -I../../../../include -I/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Versions/A/Headers -Idebug -F/Library/Frameworks -o debug/main.o main.cpp
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qnamespace.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:47,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:1572:4: error: #error "Qt not configured correctly, please run configure"
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:2705:6: error: #error "Qt not configured correctly, please run configure"
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qatomic_arch.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/thread/qbasicatomic.h:227,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/thread/qatomic.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qatomic.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:48,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_arch.h:96:4: error: #error "Qt has not been ported to this architecture"
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:47,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qnamespace.h:51: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:47,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs.h:51: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qchar.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:48,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qchar.h:51: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/thread/qatomic.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qatomic.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:48,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/thread/qbasicatomic.h:51: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qatomic.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:48,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/thread/qatomic.h:52: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:48,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h:71: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:48,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:73: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qiterator.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qlist.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:50,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qiterator.h:58: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qalgorithms.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:47,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qlist.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:50,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qalgorithms.h:51: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qlist.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:50,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:66: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qscopedpointer.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:54,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qscopedpointer.h:49: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:60: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qpointer.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qpointer.h:51: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qplugin.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qplugin.h:52: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qiodevice.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/io/qdatastream.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qdatastream.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstringlist.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qstringlist.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qfactoryinterface.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qfactoryinterface.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:46,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/io/qiodevice.h:61: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qdatastream.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstringlist.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qstringlist.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qfactoryinterface.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qfactoryinterface.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:46,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/io/qdatastream.h:57: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/io/qdatastream.h:97: error: ‘BigEndian’ is not a member of ‘QSysInfo’
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/io/qdatastream.h:98: error: ‘LittleEndian’ is not a member of ‘QSysInfo’
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qregexp.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstringlist.h:48,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qstringlist.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qfactoryinterface.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qfactoryinterface.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:46,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qregexp.h:56: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qstringmatcher.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstringlist.h:50,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qstringlist.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qfactoryinterface.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qfactoryinterface.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:46,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstringmatcher.h:51: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qstringlist.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qfactoryinterface.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qfactoryinterface.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:46,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstringlist.h:59: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qfactoryinterface.h:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:46,
                 from main.cpp:42:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qfactoryinterface.h:52: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from main.cpp:42:
/Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qsqldriverplugin.h:52: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForSqlModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qmetatype.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h:48,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qvariant.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/../../src/sql/kernel/qsqlresult.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/qsqlresult.h:1,
                 from ../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:44:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qmetatype.h:60: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qmap.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h:49,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qvariant.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/../../src/sql/kernel/qsqlresult.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/qsqlresult.h:1,
                 from ../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:44:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qmap.h:59: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qpair.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h:49,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qhash.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h:50,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qvariant.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/../../src/sql/kernel/qsqlresult.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/qsqlresult.h:1,
                 from ../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:44:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qpair.h:51: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qhash.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h:50,
                 from ../../../../include/QtCore/qvariant.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/../../src/sql/kernel/qsqlresult.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/qsqlresult.h:1,
                 from ../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:44:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h:55: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qvariant.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/../../src/sql/kernel/qsqlresult.h:45,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/qsqlresult.h:1,
                 from ../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:44:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h:57: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtCore/qvector.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/../../src/sql/kernel/qsqlresult.h:46,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/qsqlresult.h:1,
                 from ../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:44:
../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h:64: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForCoreModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtSql/qsql.h:1,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/../../src/sql/kernel/qsqlresult.h:47,
                 from ../../../../include/QtSql/qsqlresult.h:1,
                 from ../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:44:
../../../../include/QtSql/../../src/sql/kernel/qsql.h:51: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForSqlModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtSql/qsqlresult.h:1,
                 from ../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:45,
                 from main.cpp:44:
../../../../include/QtSql/../../src/sql/kernel/qsqlresult.h:53: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForSqlModule’ does not name a type
In file included from ../../../../include/QtSql/qsqldriver.h:1,
                 from ../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.h:46,
                 from main.cpp:44:
../../../../include/QtSql/../../src/sql/kernel/qsqldriver.h:57: error: ‘QtValidLicenseForSqlModule’ does not name a type
make[1]: *** [debug/main.o] Error 1
make: *** [debug] Error 2
```

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it, for future reference:

I opened up `ibase.pro` and added the following lines:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Headers
LIBS += -framework Firebird
```

Then I opened up `qsql_ibase.pri` and removed the following lines:

```
unix {
    !contains(LIBS, .*gds.*):!contains(LIBS, .*libfb.*):LIBS += -lgds
} else {
    !contains(LIBS, .*gds.*):!contains(LIBS, .*fbclient.*) {
        win32-borland:LIBS += gds32.lib
        else:LIBS += -lgds32_ms
    }
}
```

Then I created a symlink for the mysterious `qsqlcachedresult_p.h` file so it is where all the other Qt headers are:

```
mkdir /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Headers/private
ln -s ~/devel/qt/src/sql/kernel/qsqlcachedresult_p.h /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Headers/private/qsqlcachedresult_p.h
```

The QIBASE driver can now be built like so:

```
cd ~/devel/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/ibase
qmake -spec macx-g++ ibase.pro
make
```